# perl setting locale failing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vps, perl

Is there any way of fixing once and for all the problem mentioned here: http://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Perl_warning_Setting_locale_failed_unter_Debian

I keep fixing it by doing

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

But whenever I reboot, the error starts happening again. It's a Ubuntu 11.04 VPS

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you login via SSH, **your** locale (the one on the machine your are connecting from) is sent to the server. I assume, you have `de_DE.UTF-8` set locally. Whenever you execute the code snippet from Hetzner while you are logged in on the machine you *temporarily* switch to a different LC and everything works (for a while).

First off look in `/etc/default/locale`. You should find a `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` in there (if not, add it).

I would recommend to install *your* locale on the server. Try choosing any `de_DE.*` in the `dpkg-reconfigure locales` dialog..

Or you could append the `export` commands (not the other commands!) into your `~/.bashrc` on the server, so they will be set automatically whenever you login.

Or you could disable accepting `LC_*` and `LANG` variables on you SSH server (and your server should fallback to it's default). Therefore remove them from - or uncomment the whole - `AcceptEnv` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.